# Arduino controlling 4 motors through bluetooth with 2-l298N motor controllera

Tags: c, arduino

I am making a small bluetooth controlled robot. And i am using 2 L298N motor controllars, HC06 bluetooth module and arduino uno. When i am pressing forward button on the phone i want two motors to work at 50% speed and two motors to work at 100% speed. How do i make this?

Comment: simply when forward press is detected you can make motors at respective pins to work at respective speed(ex. pin X,Y at speed max_speed/2 and pin P,Q at max_speed, there are tutorials to control speed of AC/DC motors).

Comment: "How do I make my whole project" is far too broad a question for this site.

Comment: Well i just want to how to write the void forward(){what should i put in here} i can workout the rest. I am confused thats why

Comment: You might want to edit the question to be more narrow or start a new one. 
The power to the motors can be controlled by using one of the PWM capable pins on the arduino(write using analogWrite(int) function. As for changing directions, refer to L298N datasheet.

Answer (score -1):

Thank u guys,
I figured it out. 
Its digitalWrite(motorpina, HIGH);
digitalWrite(motorpinB, LOW)
Analogwrite(ENA, 255)